# SQL Server Database internal network Application

Tags: sql-server, web-applications, user-interface, internal, frontend

I have a SQL Server Database back-end. I want an internal network front-end UI, such that it is only accessible within a company network, not the web. Which platform would be best to use for a front-end UI application with a SQL Server database back-end? ASP.NET, PHP, Silverlight, or something else.

I would like to have graphs showing trends in data, and I would like to have the user to be able to select paramters on certain reports.

I do not have much experience with front-end user interfaces so I am open to just about anything. 
If you need more information just let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a front-end mainly for reports , I would suggest using [SQL Server  Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/reporting-services.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in having a better UI experience then i suggest you go with Silverlight .You wont get resizable layout ,grid and feature rich UI without using 3rd party tools in ASP.NET.

If you want your application to be used on any device than ASP.NET is the way to go since  silverlight has some compatibility issue as   you need to install plugin  for it .So it all depends upon the requirement .No idea regarding PHP or any other technology